# What is the cheapest way to mail a package from Vietnam to the United States?

Tags: usa, budget, vietnam, shipping

I'm going to be traveling in Vietnam this summer and would like to send back some tailored clothing. What's the cheapest way (can be take as long as necessary) to ship an under 10KG package to the US from Vietnam?

Comment: Have you tried post office?

Comment: put the tailored clothing in your luggages and mail/ship back your dirty laundry ! :-)

Answer (score 1):

In most every country, the local Postal System is the cheapest, but reliability is not always as high as a global courier service (FedEx, DHL, etc) and recourse in the event of lost or damaged goods is neigh impossible.

You need to consider the value of the goods being shipped, disappointment factor if they are lost and costs to send them home versus putting them in your baggage.